# How to include enviroment variables in SQLite3 query

Tags: sqlite, batch-file, command-line, windows-10, environment-variables

I'm working on writing a batch file to pull data from multiple SQLite3 databases. I need to set 2 System environment variables then use them two environment variables within my SELECT statement.As this will run against multiple databases that are the same schema, but for different site locations. Currently 14 differen locations. What I have come up with so far is my main queryrun.bat file:

```
@echo off
setx /m DateStart '20200101'
setx /m DateEnd '20200103'
sqlite3 SiteID40.db < query40.dat
TIMEOUT /t 3
sqlite3 SiteID41.db < query41.dat
```

Then the query#.dat files look like this:

```
.mode list
.separator ,
.output results40.csv
SELECT * FROM FilesActive WHERE CompactDate >= %DateStart% and CompactDate <= %DateEnd%;
.quit
```

The %DateStart% and %DateEnd% is where I am wanting to insert the system variables of the same name. I have tried using $DateStart and %DateStart% both with no luck.

Any constructive help is appreciated. I must `RE-ITERATE` though that this is `SQLite3` NOT MS SQL Server or mySQL.

Comment: check out [SQL parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#sql_parameters) in the command line doc.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus either I missed it, or the SQL parameters in the command line doc did not mention how to utilize system environment variables.

Comment: Well, you cannot expand variables in an SQL query file (`.dat`), you can do that only in the batch file; but even if it could, it would not work here because `setx` does not set variables for the current environment, so you would (additionally) need to do `set "DateStart=20200101"` and `set "DateEnd=20200103"`...

Answer (score 3):

Using the .param command in sqlite, something like this should work:

Change the .bat call from `sqlite3 SiteID40.db < query40.dat` to

`sqlite3 SiteID40.db  ".param set :DateStart %DateStart%" ".param set :DateEnd %DateEnd%" ".read query.dat"`

Change the query#.dat file SELECTs to:

`SELECT * FROM FilesActive WHERE CompactDate >= :DateStart and CompactDate <= :DateEnd;`